# Replacing precision of floating point numbers in existing file

Tags: bash

I have a large number of big files in the following format

```
step 80
1.10045e+07 1.10125e+07 1.20345e+07 2.40225e+07 4.30245e+07
1.10045e+07 1.10125e+07 1.20345e+07 2.40225e+07 4.30245e+07
1.10045e+07 1.10125e+07 1.20345e+07 2.40225e+07 4.30245e+07
1.10045e+07 1.10125e+07 1.20345e+07 2.40225e+07 4.30245e+07
step 90
1.54045e+07 1.10125e+07 1.20345e+07 2.40225e+07 4.30245e+07
1.16545e+07 1.10125e+07 1.20345e+07 2.40225e+07 4.30245e+07
1.10045e+07 1.10125e+07 1.20345e+07 2.40225e+07 4.30245e+07
1.10045e+07 1.10125e+07 1.20345e+07 2.40225e+07 4.30245e+07
...
```

The numbers are all distinct (some are the same here because of my laziness).

I want to to change the precision of the floating-point numbers. That is, I want to replace the previous file with:

```
step 80
1.10e+07    1.10e+07    1.20e+07 2.40e+07   4.30e+07
1.10e+07    1.10e+07    1.20e+07 2.40e+07   4.30e+07
1.10e+07    1.10e+07    1.20e+07 2.40e+07   4.30e+07
1.10e+07    1.10e+07    1.20e+07 2.40e+07   4.30e+07
step 90
1.54e+07    1.10e+07    1.20e+07 2.40e+07   4.30e+07
1.16e+07    1.10e+07    1.20e+07 2.40e+07   4.30e+07
1.10e+07    1.10e+07    1.20e+07 2.40e+07   4.30e+07
1.10e+07    1.10e+07    1.20e+07 2.40e+07   4.30e+07
...
```

if the desired precision is 2 digits after the decimal point.

How can I do this, in an efficient way, and low memory usage (that is, I don't to have to load the complete file to memory).

Preferably a solution using a bash script.

Comment: The formatting is the way it is because you have tabs in there. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar You're right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Perl to read the file line-by-line and reformat the numbers with [`sprintf()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html):

```
perl -pe '!/^step/ && s/(\S+)/sprintf("%.2e", $1)/ge' file
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Only downside is that `sed` is faster... but it's not working perfectly right now.

Comment: How can I call this inside gnu parallel. This doesn't work

`parallel --jobs 20 perl -ape '!/^step/ && s/(\S+)/sprintf("%.1e", $1)/ge' {} > {}.fixed ::: *`

Comment: @becko perhaps, ask a new question to resolve this issue. Also, the `-a` switch to `perl` can be omitted (as per the edit).

Answer (score 1):

As a quick & dirty solution, if the "lengthy" parts of the numbers are the only sequences longer than 2 digits at a time in front of an `'e'`...

```
sed -i "s/\([0-9]\{2\}\)[0-9]*e/\1e/g" <filename>
```

- `"s` -- search
- `/` -- begin "search" term
- `\(`  -- begin group
- `[0-9]` -- digits
- `\{2\}` -- ...two of them (edit this for different output precisions)
- `\)` -- end group
- `[0-9]*` -- followed by any number of digits
- `e` -- followed by `'e'`
- `/` -- end "search" term, begin "replace" term
- `\1` -- contents of the first group (the two first digits)
- `e` -- and the `'e'`
- `/` -- end "replace" term
- `g` -- do any number of times per line ("global")

The `-i` option (a GNU extension) does the replacing in-file, so better try it without `-i` first to make sure the output is as desired.

Comment: @LutzHorn: Much obliged.

Comment: Your condition doesn't hold. The `step` can be any any positive integer, large with many digits, or small.

Comment: @becko It should be easy to improve the matching of this answer. You have some good solutions now, use them.

Comment: @becko: Added the `'e'`. That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed 's/\(\...\)...e/\1e/g' < so.txt

step 80
1.10e+07 1.10e+07 1.20e+07 2.40e+07 4.30e+07
1.10e+07 1.10e+07 1.20e+07 2.40e+07 4.30e+07
1.10e+07 1.10e+07 1.20e+07 2.40e+07 4.30e+07
1.10e+07 1.10e+07 1.20e+07 2.40e+07 4.30e+07
step 90
1.54e+07 1.10e+07 1.20e+07 2.40e+07 4.30e+07
1.16e+07 1.10e+07 1.20e+07 2.40e+07 4.30e+07
1.10e+07 1.10e+07 1.20e+07 2.40e+07 4.30e+07
1.10e+07 1.10e+07 1.20e+07 2.40e+07 4.30e+07
```

Comment: `...`? That's new. What does it do?

Comment: The dot `.` matches *any* character. Your solution is safer :)

Comment: I thought three in a row were something special. Yes, matching any in front of an `e` is... eager. :-D

Comment: This is not working well... some entries end up having more digits, and `0.000` gets replaced by exact `0`, which is not desirable. I cannot pin-point the issue, I'll try to come up with a simple example.

Comment: It's too bad, because `sed` is *very* fast.

Comment: Well, the soultions provided here work for the input sample from your question.

Answer (score 0):

With awk you could do:

```
awk 'NF==5{printf "%.2e\t%.2e\t%.2e\t%.2e\t%.2e\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5; next}1' file
```

If the number of columns is unknown use a loop:

```
awk '!/^step/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%.2e%s", $i,i==NF?"\n":"\t";next}1' file
```

Comment: I don't know a priori how many columns there are. And there could be many more than 5, so listing them one by one is not an option. Can you improve on this?

Comment: The loop is *very* slow, for the large files I tried.