# Perl command inside GNU parallel?

Tags: perl, zsh, gnu-parallel

I am trying to run this in parallel:

```
parallel perl -pe '!/^step/ && s/(\S+)/sprintf("%.2e", $1)/ge' {} > {}.fix ::: *
```

That is, I want to execute the perl command on all files in the current directory, in parallel. This is not working, but I have no idea why.

Comment: The perl command is fixing floating-point numbers in tables. See [Replacing precision of floating point numbers in existing file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36031317/855050).

Comment: What do you mean by *“not working”*?

Comment: @Borodin I get this error: `zsh:1: no matches found: s/(S+)/sprintf(%.1e, )/ge`.

Comment: @Borodin Is the issue Zsh specific? My command runs fine in Bash (can't test because I don't have Bash enabled here)? I am asking because you tagged zsh.

Comment: I don't know zsh very well but I think it's possible. I added the zsh tag so that those who do know it might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bash you can make a function:

```
doit() {
  perl -pe '!/^step/ && s/(\S+)/sprintf("%.2e", $1)/ge' "$1" > "$2"
}
export -f doit
parallel doit {} {}.fix ::: *
```

Exporting functions in Zsh requires using a variable:

```
doit() {
  perl -pe '!/^step/ && s/(\S+)/sprintf("%.2e", $1)/ge' "$1" > "$2"
}
PARALLEL_ENV="$(typeset -f doit)"
parallel doit {} {}.fix ::: *
```

Alternatively you can quote the perl expression and the redirection (which will also work in Bash):

```
parallel perl -pe \''!/^step/ && s/(\S+)/sprintf("%.2e", $1)/ge'\' {} '>' {}.fix ::: *
```

Comment: So the error is particular to zsh? It would run fine in bash?

Comment: @becko The Zsh solution will work in both Bash and Zsh. But if you do not use a function in Bash you need to quote there aswell.

Comment: So it's not a matter of Bash vs Zsh. You just have two possible solutions, which should work in both shells. Maybe you should make that explicit.

Comment: Nope: The function-based solution does not work in Zsh. The double-quoted solution works for both.